# Looping through groupBox controls in the right order

Tags: c#, groupbox

I have a bit of code which loops through my groupBox controls and fetches the name of the control. It then writes the names into a textbox. However, the order in which they are looped through needs to be in line with the names, gb1, gb2, gb3... The order by which they are looped through right now appears to be the order in which they were created (time wise). I have tidied up the designer code so creation of the controls is ordered in the way I want it, but it appears to make no difference. Any pointers? Thanks

```
private void loopThroughControls()
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
          {                
            if (ctrl.ToString().StartsWith("System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox"))
            {
              txtEntry.Text += (ctrl.Text + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Does the order change if you change the tab index number?

Comment: No, and the tab order is set correctly anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Tomas' answer:

```
  private void LoopThroughControls()
  {
     foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(c => c.Name))
     {
        txtEntry.Text += (ctrl.Text + System.Environment.NewLine);
     }
  }
```

This will retrieve the `GroupBox` instances from the `Controls` collection, then it sorts them by their name, and then it gets the text content like you wanted.

Comment: Superb, I believe this is an example of LINQ? (which I'm completely ignorant about as an amateur developer btw)

Comment: Yes, that would be an example. I'm fairly new to it myself coming from a WinForms 2.0 environment (but now in a 4.6 WPF one), but I pick up on it extremely fast. There are some crazy fun examples of nested LINQ all over Stack Overflow. I'm sure you'll come across them in your development journey. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort the list before iterating through it?

```
foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls.OrderBy(c => c.Name))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could do. But hoping to learn something about how controls are processed.

Comment: Controls are added to the `Controls` list when they're created, and that list is not re-ordered afterwards. If you want them in a specific order, you'll have to sort them yourself. The framework usually refers to controls directly by name, which in effect searches the list (although the actual implementation is probably rather a hash lookup...).